# react-router v4's Route doesn't pass it's props to component - in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4, browser-history

I just started to use React Router v4 and can't manage to use the history of Browserrouter. For example, when I try to access `this.props.history.push("/")`I got the error:

`TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'`

I'm using React Router v4 with Browserrouter and React with Typescript. It seems that the three props (location, history, match) from React Router's Route are not passed to it's component.
**Am I doing anything wrong with Typescript or with React Router?**

*index.tsx*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router, Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "./Login";
import Questionnaire from "./Questionnaire";
import Registration from "./Registration";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
import GotNoHistory from "./GotNoHistory";
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Questionnaire}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/registration" component={Registration}/>
        <Route path="/gotNoHistory" component={GotNoHistory} />
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('reactApp')
);
```

registerServiceWorker();

*example component GotNoHistory.tsx*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './index.css';

class GotNoHistory extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.history.push("/")}</div>;
    }
}

export default GotNoHistory;
```

**Update**

I've discovered *RouteComponentProps*. I added this props to my class *GotNoHistory* and the error was gone. Is that the correct way to solve the problem?

```
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router';
class GotNoHistory extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any>, any> {
    render() {
        return <div>Go back {this.props.history.push("/")}</div>;
    }
}
```

**Update for Chris solution**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
}

interface State {
}

export default class GotNoHistory extends React.Component<Props & Route, State> {
    render() {
        return this.props.history.push("/");
    }
}
```

Results in nearly the same error: `TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{Props & Route<RouteProps>}>'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by myself.

My solution was to add the route props to the types of my props.

```
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router';
class GotNoHistory extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any>> {
    render() {
        return <div>Go back {this.props.history.push("/")}</div>;
    }
}
```

For those who don't know, like me before, what this means `<RouteComponentProps<any>>`:

The parameter ist the prop type.
So before it was only `React.Component` which means that we don't expect any props from my router. So this couldn't work out!

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know I could have multiple props like that.

Comment: Is this still necessary (to manually add it to the components props) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to it within your route components, but you need to let Typescript know you expect them as props:

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'


interface IProps {
}

interface IState {
}

export default class GotNoHistory extends React.Component<IProps & Route, IState> {
  render() {
      this.props.history.push("/");
  }
}
```

The line `IProps & Route` is saying the expected props is a combination of my own props (IProps, whatever you define that as, possibly nothing) and the Route props.

Comment: Your solution only works for the Redirect method of React Router but not for my direct access on history. The Redirect method also works on my existing original implementation. So this doesn't solve the problem. But is React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any>, any> okay? I'm telling Typescript to expect RouteComponentProps?

Comment: thank you copied your example. My Typescript error "TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{IProps & Route<RouteProps>}>'" still exists for 'history' like in the original implementation of mine.

Comment: unfortunately it's still not working. I got nearly the same error like in the original implementation but the last part of the error has changed to the new props.

Comment: Weird - its complaining about IProps, but you have renamed it to just `Props` (instead of IProps). Something isn't lining up...

Comment: sorry typo in posting the error. I had to delete the leading I in your code because of tslint rules. Edited the update, the error and the code are matching